# Unable to fork repo with `gh` command

Tags: github, github-api

I have the gihub CLI utility `gh` installed. I'm trying to follow the instructions in `gh api --help` to make an api call to fork a cloned repo on my local machine with:

`gh api /repos/:owner/:repo/forks`

This throws an error:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)
```

According to the documentation, `:owner` and `:repo` are supposed to be replaced with the appropriate values found in the current directory.

The documentation says you need to make a POST call: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork but when I try:

`gh api POST /repos/:owner/:repo/forks`

I get this error:

`accepts 1 arg(s), received 2`

**UPDATE:**
I now see the documentation says to use the `-X` options to supply the `POST` method. So now I am back to getting the first error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like I just needed to lop of the leading forward slash in the API request. So:

`gh api -X POST repos/:owner/:repo/forks`